# How does the concept of centre of mass came to existence?

Tags: physics

I am wondering as how does the concept of centre of mass came into being. Considering the usefulness of the concept how were the physicist able to define such a quantity. I mean was it just trial and error or something else? A brief history of the concept would do the job!

**Thanks!**

Comment: Certainly the intuitive idea would have been known for tens of thousands of years. For example, balancing a spear in your hand before throwing it. And especially several thousand years ago when some of the [great engineering projects of the ancient world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World) were carried out, such as the pyramids in Egypt.

Comment: This is already answered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#History), Archimedes introduced it when developing his theory of the lever.

Comment: We cannot tell for sure since most of the Hellenistic work did not survive. Based on the surviving work "On floating bodies", it seems that the concept is due to Archimedes.

Comment: Oh, look: I take a short vacation and the radio button list for Closing changed!

Comment: @CarlWhitthoft Sorry is there any problem in the question? If so tell me I would like to edit it as per the guidelines here (if possible). I'm new here!